# RegEx not recognizing slash (/) in mod_rewrite search query

Tags: regex

Can't seem to figure this one out. Here are the rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^search\/(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=$1

RewriteRule ^search&(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^search?(.*)$ index.php?route=product/search&$1 [QSA,L]
```

Works for http://mysite.com/search/whatever+terms

But, does not work for http://mysite.com/search/whatever+terms/with+slash+in+search

Returns zero results, even when there should be results.

As I'm using a wildcard, shouldn't that include the slash? What am I missing here...

**EDIT:**

Now, when I write the slash directly into the URL bar, it works... but when typed directly into the search box and rewritten as %2F, it does not. Is % a reserved character as well?

Comment: The `/` is not a reserved character in a regex, so I don't think it has to be escaped.

Comment: Was not the issue. Modified, and still not working.

Comment: You need to escape the slashes as %2F in the url i assume.

Comment: Search function automatically does that. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use:

```
search/[a-zA-Z+?&/-]+
```

Comment: Admittedly, I know next to nothing about regex. How to modify this to include all possible letters, numbers, and allowable special characters?

Comment: PeterM I would of done that however I do not have the required reputation to do so, hence I tried to help this way instead.

Furry just add options inside of the [] to include them in the url. To include numbers use 0-9 which is a range (same with a-z and A-Z) everything else just put after. For example [a-zA-Z+?&/-0-9_]+ includes the numbers 0-9 and underscores aswell. The plus means it must occur atleast once.

Comment: But doesn't `.` have all those characters and much more?

Comment: Yes but that also has spaces. That means the match will be infinite length until the string ends.

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to allow for all characters, including special characters such as asterisks, carats, dollar signs, hash signs, etc... product numbers in our catalog contain many different symbols not just standard alphanumeric. So... how to set this up to include all allowable characters, including the slash? I just checked, and if the slash is hand-written into the URL bar, it works, but when it is converted to %2F it doesn't work.

Comment: [^\s\\]+ will match any character that is not a space

Comment: Try just search\/[^\s]+